# Why are conductors important?

Tags: elliptic-curves, ramification

I'm asking about the [conductor of an elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_of_an_elliptic_curve). I'm looking at the definition given as
$$N_{E/\mathbb Q} = \prod_{p} p^{f_p},$$ 
and I understand that $f_p$ encodes information about the ramification of $p$ as follows:
$$f_p =
\begin{cases}
0 \text{, if $E$ has good reduction at $p$,}\\
1 \text{, if $E$ has multiplicative reduction at $p$,}\\
2 \text{, if $E$ has additive reduction at $p$, and $p\neq
2,3$,}\\
2+\delta_p \text{, if $E$ has additive reduction at $p=2\ or\ 3$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Above definition from [planet math](http://planetmath.org/conductorofanellipticcurve).

I think one could say the conductor is a product which represents which primes the curve has bad reduction, and how bad it is.

What I don't understand is how we go from this construction to considering it so important that databases like Cremona's and the LMFDB are principally ordered by conductor.

- [Cremona's Labeling, explained on LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/ec.q.cremona_label).
- [LMFDB Label](http://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/ec.q.lmfdb_label)

I have noticed that computing with low conductor curves is faster. Is this true? Is there a reason why low conductor would imply computational convenience when doing elliptic curve arithmetic? Does low conductor imply that the $a$-invariants will be small, or even bounded in some way?

[Elliptic curves of large rank and small conductor by Noam Elkies and Mark Watkins](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403374) is a cool paper I've been skimming, but I wish I knew why finding curves of low conductor was so motivating.

Thanks.

Comment: [Math.SE post on Definition and Meaning of Conductor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2022/definition-and-meaning-of-the-conductor-of-an-elliptic-curve) has a lot of theory explanation, but I don't understand why the theory explained there gives the conductor such significance.

Comment: I think that the post you quoted gives you a lot of good reasons why the conductor is a very important invariant. Just to quote some of them: it is also the conductor of the Galois representation on the Tate module of the curve (and it therefore measure the ramification of that representation), it is the smallest level of a modular curve which admits a nontrivial map to the elliptic curve, it enters the functional equation of the $L$-function of the curve and it is divided by the places of bad reduction. To me, this looks like more than enough... Do you want to hear another reason?

Comment: Faltings theorem implies that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of elliptic curves of a given conductor, so the conductor also gives you a natural way to order isomorphism classes of elliptic curves. Curves with small conductors are faster to compute because modular symbols algorithms become slow when the conductor - which corresponds to the level of the cuspidal space that is computed - becomes large.

Comment: Thank you, Ferra, your clarification helps. I think I understand better now, I wasn't paying much attention to the definition in terms of levels of modular curves before.